# How we can add category Filter to assign product grid

Tags: magento2, product, filter, assign

I want to add a category filter to the assigned product grid in Magento 2.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to Admin Panel
2. Go to **Stores > Attributes > Product**
3. Search for `category_ids` under the **Attribute Code** column.
4. Click on attribute row to Edit.
5. Under **Properties** tab, expand `Advanced Attribute Properties` section.
6. Set "**Use in Filter Options**" to `Yes`.
   [image]

That's all you need to do, you will have categories in the product grid filter section.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/2014ke4
I need category coulum with filter applicable

Comment: Where do you want these column filters?

Answer (score 0):

this article will gonna help you: [rohanhapani article](https://www.rohanhapani.com/add-category-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento-2-admin/)